# How to trace slow query back to code in WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, mariadb

I have a slow website. I've used database profiling tools like SolarWinds and New Relic to identify a query that is running many times and accounts for around 20% of database load:

```
SELECT meta_id ,  
   post_id ,  
   meta_key ,  
   meta_value  
FROM xxxxxxxxx . wp_postmeta
```

These tools don't do much to help in tracing the query back to code. The query doesn't show up in Wordpress Query Monitor plugin so we can't trace it using that.

There are no cron jobs running, no REST API activity, so we can be quite sure that it is the front end that is causing the query.

Is there a good strategy for tracing this query? Could there be a reason why it isn't easy to find?

Comment: Please post A) complete query, B)TEXT results of  EXPLAIN SELECT (rest of your query); so we can see what the Optimizer has done for your request, C) TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta; and D) SHOW INDEX FROM wp_postmeta; for cardinality counts of columns.

Comment: @WilsonHauck how will information about the database assist in tracing the origin of the query from code?

Comment: This is a request for information about this one specific query, the optimizers conclusion on how to run it, how the table was created and current indexes for one table - a very focused request about a single query and the one table used to provide your results.  The posting of this information may help someone direct you to the code origin. When we ask for your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; we will be looking much broader at your instance.  If you provide these results through pastebin.com we will likely provide you with some suggestions to improve OVERALL response time.